# media files aren't serving in django app on cpanel

Tags: python, django, web-deployment

I have a django app running on cpanel (I'm not sure if is a problem of my 
 django app or cpanel server), when the debug mode is set up `True`. I can see all the media files, like profiles pictures or pdf files, etc. But when the debug mode is set up `False`, you can't see the media files on the app. This is my configuratios on the `settings.py` file.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    ]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '<app-directory>/public_html/static'

# Media files
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Crispy Form Theme - Bootstrap 3
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3'

# For Bootstrap 3, change error alert to 'danger'
from django.contrib import messages
MESSAGE_TAGS = {
    messages.ERROR: 'danger'
}
```

Comment: did you execute the 'collectstatic' command? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/#deployment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To deploy a production server, you need to set 3 things

1. deactivate the DEBUG configuration:

> DEBUG = False

This disable all extra function for development.

2. define a static root directory in the settings file:

> STATIC_ROOT = '/this/is/a/path/to/statics'

This, indicate where all the static files should be saved.

3. run the command to collect all static files:

> python manage.py collectstatic

This saves all statics files in the directory configured by `STATIC_ROOT`

The official documentation for deployment:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/#static-root-and-static-url

Comment: I'm glad that it worked. If you think this is the answer you can mark it as it. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry! but I don't have the reputation yet

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually solve it yet but you can do as below to solve your issue:

1 - Setup your media and static root:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

2 - Activate your virtual enviroment on cpanel then run this command:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

3 - After you did that 2 folder will create at root of your app on cpanel
"static" and "media" folder copy both of them into "public_html" directory

4 - go to the setup python app in cpanel and find your app and restart it.

It will solve the issue for me but every time when i upload some picture i should go and just copy the media files into public_html

Comment: This is a bad approach and very cumbersome

Comment: @DennisGathagu is right, this solution needs lot of work, but it will solve the issue for the problem

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue for 1 day but I found solution. You can install this two packages dj-static static3 with pip:

```
$ pip install dj-static static3
```

then change your wsgi.py file like below:

```
.
.
.
from dj_static import Cling
.
.
.
application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```