# Django statics returns 404 error in cPanel Passenger

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I used cPanel and deployed a Django application on my server using `passenger_wsgi.py`. The problem is when I'm trying to access static files (like admin CSS file: `static/admin/css/base.css`) I'm facing with 404 error.
I've already done `collectstatic` and added `PassengerPathInfoFix` method to `passenger_wsgi.py` file but the output log is

> Not Found: /home/mysite/public_html/build/static/admin/css/base.css

even though the outputted path exists and I can edit it using `vim`.

My `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django runserver not serving static files in development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398600/django-runserver-not-serving-static-files-in-development)

Comment: @IvanStarostin No, I've copied "static" to the base directory of my domain and it works. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Ali's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68897849/9817841), For anyone with the same problem, here are the steps I've done.
Wish it would be helpful:

1. Make sure your `settings.py` file contains these lines:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
```

2. run `python manage.py collectstatic`
3. Edit your `passenger_wsgi.py` and add these lines:

```
# ...
# Import WSGI of your project

# Project Static File Path
cwd = os.getcwd()
sys.path.append(cwd)
sys.path.append(cwd + '/myapp')
SCRIPT_NAME = os.getcwd()
class PassengerPathInfoFix(object):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        from urllib.parse import unquote
        environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = SCRIPT_NAME
        request_uri = unquote(environ['REQUEST_URI'])
        script_name = unquote(environ.get('SCRIPT_NAME', ''))
        offset = request_uri.startswith(script_name) and len(environ['SCRIPT_NAME']) or 0
        environ['PATH_INFO'] = request_uri[offset:].split('?', 1)[0]
        return self.app(environ, start_response)

application = PassengerPathInfoFix(application)
```

4. If you deployed your Django project in a subfolder inside `public_html` and not in the `public_html` directory (as mine), copy the `static` folder to `public_html` or create symbolic link using `ln -s public_html/static/ public_html/subfolder/static/` (The point is the `static` files only load from your domain/subdomain base directory) (maybe there is a better solution but this solved my problem)

So I moved the project to the base directory of my domain and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Add this into url.py

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: @MVB he wants **static**, not media file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change STATIC_URL to STATICFILES_DIRS, this work with me!

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static',
    BASE_DIR / 'static/admin',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

install whitenoise and that's it !

1. `pip install whitenoise`
2. settings.py :

   ```
   MIDDLEWARE = [
       # ...
       "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
       "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
       # ...
   ]
   ```